# Flex - Button to simulate key press

Tags: apache-flex, events, simulate

I have a TextArea with undo/redo which is performed via ctrl+z, ctrl+y. My app is a mobile app with no cntrl on the soft keyboard so I want to make an undo and a redo button which simulates the keypresses. How do you simulate keys in Flex?

Answer (score 1):

You can dispatch any event you like including KeyboardEvents so to dispatch a KeyboardEvent that simulates ctrl-z (keycode 26) and ctrl-y (keycode 25) you could do something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                this.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyHandler );
            }

            protected function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                this.dispatchEvent( new KeyboardEvent( KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, true, false, 26, 26, 0, true ) );
            }

            protected function keyHandler( e:KeyboardEvent ):void
            {
                trace(e.charCode, e.keyCode, e.ctrlKey);
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Button id="undoButton" label="undo" click="clickHandler(event)" />
</mx:Application>
```

The line `this.dispatchEvent( new KeyboardEvent( KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, true, false, 26, 26, 0, true ) );` is the key (no pun intended) it says dispatch a KEY_UP event, the next two args are bubbles and cancelable, then 26 for both charCode and keyCode, 0 for keyLocation, and finally true for ctrlKey (to simulate it being down).

Comment: I've tried this and I get 26 26 true traced when I click the button but the text doesn't undo. I'm sure I'm missing something simple as your example is clear and makes sense. Any idea what it might be?

Comment: It might be that the component listening for KeyBoardEvents is lower than the button sending out the event. In Flash and Flex events can bubble up the DisplayList so that any components further up the chain can hear them or you can explicitly listen for an event from a component. Is the textarea undo/redo something you built or is it a third party thing?

Comment: It's actually just the spark TextArea

Comment: Ok after looking at this more closely the textarea can only do undo/redo while it has focus once you click out of it undo and redo history is lost. Since clicking on a button changes the focus you won't be able to have an undo button with the built in undo. You could build your own undo/redo management it's a little bit painful just for one textarea, but if you're interested checkout the Momento pattern http://lucamezzalira.com/2010/01/12/memento-pattern-in-actionscript-3-undoredo.